# restoring deleted file using bash in unix

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, unix

good evening

i have a task to complete and have tried the following but does not work

```
#!/bin/bash

FPath=$(grep $1 $HOME/.restore.info | cut -d":" -f2)
FName=$(grep $1 $HOME/.restore.info | cut -d":" -f1)
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
        echo "No input detected"
        exit $?

elif [ "$FName" = $1 ]
then
        echo " Match found and restored to its original location"
        mv ~/deleted/$1 $FPath
else
        echo "File does not exist"
        exit $?
fi
```

it is supposed to restore deleted files in a specific folder to its original location

however, it keeps saying file does not exist, even though the file exists.

i also need to create a case for the existing files and if user chooses to over write the existing files. please help me with this too

i appreciate your assistance

Comment: If any filename contains spaces the script will fail due to missing quotes. Write `"$1"` instead of `$1`, `"$(...)"` instead of `$(...)` and so on (but *don't* quote the `~`, that has to stay unquoted :)

Comment: thanks for the reply, i have done what you have noted but still shows the same error message

Comment: Seems that `"$FName" = $1` is not true. So try echoing them and make sure that they are equal.

Comment: Thank you very much Arash. you were absolutely right the path was not correct i have amended the path as following :  and the code all started working   #!/bin/bash

FPath="$(grep "$1" $HOME/.restore.info | cut -d":" -f2)"
FName="$(grep "$1" $HOME/.restore.info | cut -d":" -f1)"
echo $FPath
echo $FName
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
        echo "No input detected"
        exit 1
else
if [ "$1" = $FName ]
then
        echo " Match found and restored to its original location"
        mv ~/deleted/$1 $FPath
else
        echo "File does not exist"
        exit 1
fi
fi

Comment: Edit your question so you can format your code. And show how `.restore.info` looks like. And an example how you call the script (file with full path?).

Answer (score 0):

`$FPath` and `$FName` will go into infinite wait if `$#` is really is 0, that means it will never get to rest of the lines.

If you had that taken care of:
ignore case in your grep:
`grep -i $1 $HOME/.restore.info | cut -d":" -f2`

capture the first occurrence in your grep if there are multiple entries for $1
`grep -i $1 $HOME/.restore.info | cut -d":" -f2 | head -1`

Comment: it worked with amended command above for restoring two files only. Now its showing once more File does not exist. what do you think is the problem? the path and name are both echo ing fine. and if no input detected it always says no input detected so that does not go into infinite wait

Comment: How is this script being called? could you show me how you run in getting the "File does not exist?